# How to load a form but without stealing focus?

Tags: c#, windows

When my C# app runs I want it to start minimized and to show on the taskbar but without stealing the focus from the current app (to load in background).

I tried this but it doesn't work in Windows 10:

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the form's `WindowState = Minimized` should be enough.

Comment: thank you for the edit MickyD, learn something new every day.

Comment: I already used that. The form still has focus on taskbar (its button is activated). I don't want any kind of focus on that taskbar button.

Comment: @FloatingAway unfortunately this is not the behavior I'm seeing on my own computer. The application starts and does not receive focus.